# How can I select data and the total to cursors?

Tags: oracle, select

I have a table like this:

```
 ID  | Name
------------
  1  | AA
  2  | AA
  3  | AA
  4  | BB
```

I want to select all rows where Name like `'AA'` in a cursor and get the count from this result in another cursor. I also need to page the results.

Expected result (Skip = 0; Take = 2)

```
-- p_result

 ID  | Name
------------
  1  | AA
  2  | AA

-- p_count
   3
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An alternative to msi77's solution is the use of analytical functions. This *might* be a bit more efficient but you should run an explain plan to find out.

```
SELECT id,
       name, 
       count(*) over () as total_count
FROM your_table
WHERE name = 'AA'
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure to understand what you really want, but i'd suggest to try the following:

```
SELECT   ID, Name, 'p_result' AS Type
FROM     xy
ORDER BY Name

UNION

SELECT   COUNT(1), Name, 'p_count' AS Type
FROM     xy
GROUP BY Name
```

It's untested, but it could show you sth. like this:

```
 ID  | Name | Type
-----------------------
  1  | AA   | p_result
  2  | AA   | p_result
  3  | AA   | p_result
  4  | BB   | p_result
  3  | AA   | p_count
  1  | BB   | p_count
```

Disadvantage of this is, that you merge all the information together. Maybe 2 queries might be more helpful in your case!

Comment: Two queries with two exact same WHERE conditions is too much risk. I someone forget to update both queries it will break return inconsistent results. I want all results (4) then return only the page 1 (row 1 and row 2), and set the count to 4 (total of rows).

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in one query:

```
select *, (select COUNT(*) from table where Name=p.Name) from table p
where Name='AA'
```